# Amazon MWS MwsJsonBuilder and format for date in json

Tags: json, date, amazon-mws, iso8601

I'm using Amazon MWS API. When using mock requests provided by the lib **MerchantFulfillment**, I see that the `com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsJsonBuilder` returns an ISO8601 date not wrapped into a string. E.g.

```
  {  
   "xmlns":"https:\/\/mws.amazonservices.com\/MerchantFulfillment\/2015-06-01",
   "CancelShipmentResult":{  
      "Shipment":{  
         "ShipmentId":"String",
         "AmazonOrderId":"String",
         "SellerOrderId":"String",
         "ItemList":[  
            {  
               "OrderItemId":"String",
               "Quantity":1
            }
         ],
         "ShipFromAddress":{  
            "Name":"String",
            "AddressLine1":"String",
            "AddressLine2":"String",
            "AddressLine3":"String",
            "DistrictOrCounty":"String",
            "Email":"String",
            "City":"String",
            "StateOrProvinceCode":"String",
            "PostalCode":"String",
            "CountryCode":"String",
            "Phone":"String"
         },
         "ShipToAddress":{  
            "Name":"String",
            "AddressLine1":"String",
            "AddressLine2":"String",
            "AddressLine3":"String",
            "DistrictOrCounty":"String",
            "Email":"String",
            "City":"String",
            "StateOrProvinceCode":"String",
            "PostalCode":"String",
            "CountryCode":"String",
            "Phone":"String"
         },
         "PackageDimensions":{  
            "Length":100,
            "Width":100,
            "Height":100,
            "Unit":"String",
            "PredefinedPackageDimensions":"String"
         },
         "Weight":{  
            "Value":100,
            "Unit":"String"
         },
         "Insurance":{  
            "CurrencyCode":"String",
            "Amount":100
         },
         "ShippingService":{  
            "ShippingServiceName":"String",
            "CarrierName":"String",
            "ShippingServiceId":"String",
            "ShippingServiceOfferId":"String",
            "ShipDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z,
            "EarliestEstimatedDeliveryDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z,
            "LatestEstimatedDeliveryDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z,
            "Rate":{  
               "CurrencyCode":"String",
               "Amount":100
            },
            "ShippingServiceOptions":{  
               "DeliveryExperience":"String",
               "DeclaredValue":{  
                  "CurrencyCode":"String",
                  "Amount":100
               },
               "CarrierWillPickUp":true,
               "LabelFormat":"String"
            },
            "AvailableLabelFormats":[  
               "String"
            ]
         },
         "Label":{  
            "CustomTextForLabel":"String",
            "Dimensions":{  
               "Length":100,
               "Width":100,
               "Unit":"String"
            },
            "FileContents":{  
               "Contents":"String",
               "FileType":"String",
               "Checksum":"String"
            },
            "LabelFormat":"String",
            "StandardIdForLabel":"String"
         },
         "Status":"String",
         "TrackingId":"String",
         "CreatedDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z,
         "LastUpdatedDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z
      }
   },
   "ResponseMetadata":{  
      "RequestId":"String"
   }
}
```

So, for instance, `"EarliestEstimatedDeliveryDate":1969-07-21T02:56:03Z` does not look like a valid JSON. Jackson's `ObjectMapper` fails, clearly, complaining about the hyphen.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: According to http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm the official JSON spec does not specify any date format, so various environments will make up their own way of expressing dates.

Comment: @GerardAshton it believe it is wrong. They do not specify a standard for the content, but the content should be in double quotes.